# How can I hide username and password in connection string in Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an app service and in the Configuration section there is a connection string that connect to a database as follows:

```
Server=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=myDataBase;User 
ID=mylogin@myserver;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;
```

How can I hide the plain text password utilizing Azure services or anything else?

Comment: Change the app code to read the UserID and Password from a Secrets store. Or setup Azure Active Directory and use Integrated Security.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Key Vault is a good way to hide credentials in connection strings in an Azure Web App. Here's an overview of the steps you can follow:

1. Create an Azure Key Vault instance.
2. Add the connection strings you want to store as secrets in the Key
   Vault.
3. Grant access to the Azure Web App to retrieve secrets from the Key
   Vault.
4. In the Azure Web App, retrieve the connection strings from the Key
   Vault at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

As a general approach: Use [Key Vault-referenced App Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli) in Azure App Service.

Your preferred way, however, should be to use [Managed Identity of the App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=portal%2Chttp) and then use Azure AD-based authentication for all services which support it ([Azure SQL does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-powershell)).

Comment: With the Managed Identity , I have tried that , but does it require changes to the way the app creates a db connection ?

Comment: @Jennifer did you look at the links I provided? It also has an example for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-powershell#using-an-azure-ad-identity-to-connect-from-a-client-application

Comment: I have followed the example on the link provided , but get an error in the url, error?database, which means its connection string .  I have read elsewhere that I need to include a sqlclient dll in the code .. ?

Comment: I get the error , "Failed to resolve the UPN for the current windows account."

Comment: any ideas on how i can get this working ?